# utf8mb4_unicode_ci и utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, utf-8

Установил laravel 5.4. Вышла ощибка

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table users add unique users_email_unique(email))[PDOException]SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

На laravel-news.com посоветовали поставить

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Но теперь ошибки выходят, так как varchar 191 символ, а раньше было 255.
Вот и вопрос, могу ли я поставить на utf8mb4_unicode_ci длинну в 255 символов? Или что делать, если мне нужна длинна в 255 символов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть два способа:

1. способ

Если вам необходима длинна строки до 255 символов, то необходимо в конфигурационном файле

```
/config/database.php
```

в массиве **['connections']['mysql']**
(Если у вас используется БД MySQL) заменить строки с:

```php
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',  
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

На следующие:

```
'charset' => 'utf8',  
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

2. Способ

Если вы будете использовать сопоставление *utf8mb4*
В файле сервис провайдера

```bash
/app/Providers/AppServicepRovider.php
```

В метод **boot()** вставить код:

```php
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы нашли правильный код, только не в тот файл вставили его. AppServiceProvider.php - в этот файл попробуйте вставить, у меня после этого все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы дальше работать с символами с длиной 255, Вам нужно обновить `mysql` сервер до последней версии